# Error in Linkdatagen : Use of uninitiated value $chr in concatenation (.) or string

Tags: perl, syntax-error, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format, bcftools

Hi I was trying to use linkdatagen, which is a perl based tool. It requires a vcf file (using mpileup from SAMtools) and a hapmap annotation file (provided). I have followed the instructions but the moment I use the perl script provided, I get this error.
The codes I used are:

```
samtools mpileup -d10000 -q13 -Q13 -gf hg19.fa -l annotHapMap2U.txt samplex.bam | bcftools view -cg -t0.5 - > samplex.HM.vcf

Perl vcf2linkdatagen.pl -variantCaller mpileup -annotfile annotHapMap2U.txt -pop CEU -mindepth 10 -missingness 0 samplex.HM.vcf > samplex.brlmm
```

`Use of uninitiated value $chr in concatenation (.) or string  at vcf2linkdatagentest.pl line 487, <IN> line 1`.... it goes on and on.. I have mailed the authors, and haven't heard from them yet. Can anyone here please help me? What am I doing wrong?

The perl script is :
http://bioinf.wehi.edu.au/software/linkdatagen/vcf2linkdatagen.pl

The HapMap file can be downloaded from the website mentioned below.
http://bioinf.wehi.edu.au/software/linkdatagen/

Thanks so much

Comment: By the way, you might want to let the authors know that `my $chr = $1 if ($tmp[0] =~ /chr([\S]+)/);`, which is a buggy way of writing `my ($chr) = $tmp[0] =~ /chr([\S]+)/;`.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring lines starting with `#`, `vcf2linkdatagen.pl` expects the first field of the first line of the VCF to contain something of the form "chr*something*", and your file doesn't meet that expectation. Examples from a comment in the code:

```
chr1    888659  .   T   C   226 .   DP=26;AF1=1;CI95=1,1;DP4=0,0,9,17;MQ=49;FQ=-81  GT:PL:GQ    1/1:234,78,0:99
chr1    990380  .   C   .   44.4    .   DP=13;AF1=7.924e-09;CI95=1.5,0;DP4=3,10,0,0;MQ=49;FQ=-42    PL  0
```

Comment: But that is supposed to happen when I am using the mpileup code for generating vcf. Is it possible that it is a glitch in the vcf2linkdatagen.pl code, at line 487?

Comment: I don't know anything about `mpileup` or VCF files. You asked why you're getting the warning, and I told you why.

Answer (score 0):

The warning means that a variable used in a string is not initialized (undefined). It is an indication that something might be wrong. The line in question can be traced to this statement

```
my $chr = $1 if ($tmp[0] =~ /chr([\S]+)/);
```

It is bad practice to use postfix if statements on a `my` statement.

As ikegami notes a workaround for this might be

```
my ($chr) = $tmp[0] =~ /chr([\S])/;
```

But since the match failed, it will likely return the same error. The only way to solve is to know more about the purpose of this variable, if the error should be fatal or not. The author has not handled this case, so we do not know.

If you want to know more about the problem, you might add a debug line such as this:

```
warn "'chr' value not found in the string '$tmp[0]'" unless defined $chr;
```

Typically, an error like this occurs when someone gives input to a program that the author did not expect. So if you see which lines give this warning, you might find out what to do about it.

Comment: Re "*Because if the condition fails, does the variable exist?*", Since `my`'s compile-time effect creates the variable, that's not the problem. The problem is that the variable won't be cleared on scope exit unless `my` gets executed. This is why this code is documented to have undefined behaviour.